# How to get data from the POST json

Tags: ios, json, swift, authentication, alamofire

I am creating a login page where once the user enters username password then the data is send to the API and if the entered data is correct then returns success . If the result is success, i need to get the user key of the user which is returned by the serverin this form :

```
{
    "STATUS_DESC": "Success",
    "STATUS_CODE": 1,
    "email": "keshurai1024@gmail.com",
    "api_token": "Mqbraok1zsdasdasd4j3m"
 }
```

Now i need to store this api token. 
For this i am trying this function but its not working -

```
@IBAction func signInBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let email : String! = self.usernameField.text
    let password : String! = self.passwordField.text

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(URL_BASE)\(AUTH)\(LOGIN)")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "email=\(email!)&&password=\(password!)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            print("cant run")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            print("\(email)")
            print("\(password)")


        }
        else {
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
            print("\(URL_BASE)\(AUTH)\(LOGIN)/?\(postString)")
            Alamofire.request("\(URL_BASE)\(AUTH)\(LOGIN)/?\(postString)" , method : .post).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result
        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        {
            print(dict)
        let userTOKEN = dict["api_token"] as! String
            print(userTOKEN)
            }

            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Please tell me what mistake m doing and how can i correct it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for parsing Data to json:

```
 if let jsonData = data {
      do {
           let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : Any]
           print(jsonResult)
           print(jsonResult?["api_token"])

           //Here we saving aoi_token to UserDefaults:
           UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "api_token")
           print("\(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "api_token")!)")
    } catch {
           print("JSON Processing Failed")
    }
}
```

And to store your api_token you need to use UserDefaults:

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "api_token")
print("\(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "api_token")!)")
```

Comment: I edited the answer. I added code to store api_token to UserDefaults. Put this code into response closure of your data task.

Comment: let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in { //Put code here }

Comment: but still .. it will only execute only if the username and password are correct ..

Comment: Yes. You need to add additional checking for server error and response structure.

Comment: @Serhii Londar you should never save token in user defaults.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't understand why you are using `URLSession`. You can just use `Alamofire` which is a wrapper around `URLSession`.

```
@IBAction func signInBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let email : String = self.usernameField.text ?? ""
    let password : String = self.passwordField.text ?? ""

    Alamofire.request("\(URL_BASE)\(AUTH)\(LOGIN)/",
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: ["email": email,
                                  "password", password],
                      encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { response in 

                      if let dict = response.value as? [String: Any] {
                          let token = dict["api_token"] as! String

                          //store token
                          UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "token")  
                          UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                      }


                      let savedToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token")    
                      print(savedToken)

        }

}
```

Comment: thanks but how can i solve my problem by doing the same wa

Comment: @KeshuRai Which way? using only `URLSession`?

Comment: i can replace URLSession with Almaofire . thats not an issue .. i just need to store the response i.e. the api_token of the user to a local variable so that i can use it further ..

Comment: You need to store it in `UserDefaults` for that.

Comment: it isnt throwing any error but the token is not printing and the value is not parsed ..

Comment: Try now. If you still get nothing set breakpoint and investigate.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain what the heck is wrong with this answer?